# how to parse string into json

Tags: javascript, json

i have difficulty when i try to parse the following string into json can anybody gauide me or suggest me proper way of parsing following json string

```
'[{"club_id":"19","club_name":"Al Lawrence","club_desc":"We welcome anyone who enjoys the camaraderie of competition at any level.   Al currently coaches many Houston area runners ranging from elite to back-of-the-packers.  Today the club still has a number of members who receive professional independent coaching from Al, but that certainly is not a requirement for membership in the Al Lawrence Running Club.","club_latitude":"29.770042","club_longitude":"-95.37","club_zip":"77001","club_member_size":"93","club_size":"s","club_type":"training","club_url":"http:\/\/www.alrcus.org\/","club_img":"1390975493.jpg","is_published":"1"},{"club_id":"20","club_name":"Bay Area Fit","club_desc":"Welcome to Houston FIT! We are a group of training partners and friends preparing together for a full or half marathon in 2013\/2014. Even if you\u2019ve never run a step before, training with our group will help you conquer mental and physical barriers you never thought possible.","club_latitude":"29.564405","club_longitude":"-95.091113","club_zip":"77058","club_member_size":"302","club_size":"l","club_type":"training","club_url":"http:\/\/www.houstonfit.com\/","club_img":"1390975687.jpg","is_published":"1"},{"club_id":"22","club_name":"Bay Area Running Club","club_desc":"Order now before the next HARRA race!  Password texas.  Color, size and logo location options available plus you can add BARC on the back for just $5 more.  Flat shipping rate of $4.95 if you buy one or two singlets and no tax!  Orders are shipped out 24-48 hours after purchase. ","club_latitude":"29.583945","club_longitude":"-95.033832","club_zip":"77586","club_member_size":"450","club_size":"l","club_type":"non-training","club_url":"http:\/\/www.barchouston.com\/","club_img":"1390989179.jpg","is_published":"1"},{"club_id":"29","club_name":"Houston Harriors","club_desc":"The 1st race of the HARRA 2014 Spring Series\r\nSaturday, February 22nd, 2014 Houston, Texas\r\nSponsored by the Houston Harriers","club_latitude":"29.733042110628393","club_longitude":"-95.33655524253845","club_zip":"77001","club_member_size":"0","club_size":"","club_type":"tranning","club_url":"http:\/\/www.houstonharriers.com\/","club_img":"1391078677.jpg","is_published":"1"}]'
```

i have tried by `eval()` and `JSON.parse` method but error arise

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Comment: It is an array. That is why `JSON.parse` doesn't work.

Comment: @Danny — JSON allows an array at the top level.

Comment: @Quentin ah, never knew that. Figured it didn't.

Comment: The string is already JSON. You are trying to convert from JSON to a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have control characters inside a JSON string.

Your JavaScript string literal includes:

```
"The 1st race of the HARRA 2014 Spring Series\r\nSaturday, February 22nd, 2014 Houston, Texas\r\nSponsored by the Houston Harriers"
```

This gets converted to this fragment of JSON:

```
"The 1st race of the HARRA 2014 Spring Series
Saturday, February 22nd, 2014 Houston, Texas
Sponsored by the Houston Harriers"
```

The literal new lines are forbidden. If you want them in the data, then you'll have to escape the escape characters in the JavaScript:

```
"The 1st race of the HARRA 2014 Spring Series\\r\\nSaturday, February 22nd, 2014 Houston, Texas\\r\\nSponsored by the Houston Harriers"
```

---

In general, however, assuming the JSON is from a trusted source, you shouldn't be embedded a string literal of JSON in JavaScript in the first place. Just take away the `'` from the start and end and you'll have a JavaScript object literal that doesn't need parsing inside the JS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is arising from the escape characters in the JSON. For example: `http:\/\/` and `\n`.

If you double-escape them (`http:\\/\\/` and `\\n`), the parse will work:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/Pam2T/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the data itself where you have `\r\n` this is because you cannot have contorl chars in a json string.

If you remove them it all works correctly see the fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/DwXnb/

Comment: Control characters may not be valid, but escape sequences are. They don't need to be removed, they just need to be escaped for *both* `'` and `"` strings. `\\r\\n`